# How to set a user meta key value based on another user meta key value

Tags: user-meta

Each of the 7,000+ users on my site has around 25 keys in the usermeta table.  I won't list them all, but two of the keys are "access_code" and "association".

There are several dozen unique access codes for my site and each user is assigned only one access code.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I want to find all the users with the access_code key with value "abc" and for each of those users where that value is true, their association key would change to "XYZ Corporation".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a meta query for this.

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'access_code',
        'value'   => 'abc',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);

$args =  array(
  'meta_query'   => $meta_query_args
);

$users = get_users( $args );

// User Loop
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
  update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'association', 'XYZ Corporation');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Pim!  I'll definitely give this a shot.  Here comes a dumb question first.  Where does this code go?  It doesn't look like I'm supposed to put it into the SQL tab in phpmyadmin....  How do I execute this?

Comment: You can put it at the end of `functions.php` inside your theme folder. Make sure you back up your DB beforehand!

Comment: Will do and will let you know how it worked.  Thanks again!

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you again, Pim!!!  Here's another question for you.  Can I copy/paste this query into my functions.php multiple times (once for each access code) so it automatically enters the association for each future user?  I would think yes, but you seem to know what you're doing so I thought I'd ask before I do it.

Comment: Yes you can, you can also change this one. And you should remove it from your `functions.php`once it's done, otherwise it will be run each time you visit a page on your site. Please consider upvoting/marking the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Got it.  Sounds like I shouldn't keep it there permanently.  Marking now.  Many thanks!